# Crystal Reports- use other records for condition?

Tags: database, if-statement, syntax, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

I am somewhat new to crystal reports and the syntax involved, and cannot seem to find the specifics by searching.

The problem is,

I need to check a condition of another record (linked as in image) for when `Op No=10` in table `Route`, I must then check the `Date Complete` of this record in table `WO Route Schedule` for the same OP (see image for how they are linked) with a date input by user when the report is ran.

[Table links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBock.png)

The jist is, im trying to show the font of a field in red when `Date Complete>=FDate` (user) (FOR OP 10), but since the actual list i am generating is of `OPs that are not 10`, I cannot seem to point crystal to look for when `Op No=10`, which is linked to the current OP by `Route_ID and Work Order_ID!` I have been trying many If statements, as well as using a case statement for when `Op_No=10`, but to no avail.

As a novice, I am not entirely sure of what other information is needed. Hopefully the images help explain my motive, but please ask for more info if you think this problem can be solved.

Regards

EDIT: More context if it helps (first comment)

Yeah it's hard to explain without overdoing the details, but each work order (WO) has around 100 operations (OPs). Now, crystal reports generates a list of OPs which are still active on the shop floor, but firstly it must check if a certain OP has been completed FOR THAT work order, which then produces a field with red font for when OP number 10 is completed. Now, if I was to simply put If {WO_Route_Schedule.Date_Complete}>={?FDate} , it would use the current OPs complete date, not OP No 10 for that Work order!

Comment: I am sorry to say but I couldn't get exactly what your requirement is?

Comment: Yeah it's hard to explain without overdoing the details, but each work order (WO) has around 100 operations (OPs). Now, crystal reports generates a list of OPs which are still active on the shop floor, but firstly it must check if a certain OP has been completed FOR THAT work order, which then produces a field with red font for when OP number 10 is completed.                                        Now, if I was to simply put If {WO_Route_Schedule.Date_Complete}>={?FDate} , it would use the current OPs complete date, not OP No 10 for that Work order!

Comment: ok let me summarize what I understood.. you need date for op=10 and then check the date enter by user and if both maches` then you want to change the `font to red` for that field...am i right? In this case do you need the records for `op not equal to 10` aswell

Comment: Yeah that sounds about right. Basically when OP 10 is complete, the Work order becomes "Kitted", and if the work order is "kitted" since the date input from user, then it must highlight red. I know the If statement to allow this to happen, however I am not sure how to tell Crystal to "pick/choose" Op No 10, and then use the Date tied to this? Thanks

Comment: "In this case do you need the records for op not equal to 10 aswell" yeah these would just stay as font crBlack!

Answer (score 0):

ok try below solution:

1. Place below condition in `record selection formula` .

   ```
   {WO_Route_Schedule.Date_Complete}>={?FDate}
   ```

   to find record selection formula go to `File--> selectin formula ---> record`
2. Place the op field `OP No` in detail section,
3. Now right click the op no field go to `Format field ---> Tab Font ---> formula editor of color`

write below condition there

```
if Op No=10
then crRed
else crBlack
```

Let me know how it goes

Comment: No avail, unfortunately I don't think what I'm looking for is possible with reporting software. I need to somehow _grab_ the `WO_ID`, then use this to trace back to the `OP no`, change this to `10`, then trace all the way back to the `table WO_Route_Schedule`, and then use: `If (FOR OP 10 of same WO) {WO_Route_Schedule.Date_Complete}>={?FDate} then crRed else crBlack`. Thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: why where are you struck? what is the problem with the solution?

Comment: The solution seems to pull different records than what is expected, and there is no red fields produced. If I knew how to use `OP No 10` for the exact same `WO_ID` as the actual OP crystal is looking at. then use this to find the date completion of `OP 10` for same `WO_ID`.

Comment: I don't know how you took the solution but linking needs to be done in links tab of crystal reports and fields and filtering need to be applied in CR itself. edited my answer and put 10 inplace of 1

Comment: I can see where your solution is coming from, but the problem is definitely with my explanation as I dont have much experience with this. Also the report has been used for over a year Im just trying to improve it by highlighting changes since `[user date]` in red to speed things up in office...  Therefore changing the record selection might break what is already there. If I can think of a better way to word this, then I will edit, or if I solve it I will answer with my own solution. Thanks!

Comment: The key reason (I think) that solution isn't working is because the OPs that Crystal is listing are never going to be OP No=10, which is why im struggling for Crystal to find the OP=10 that is linked with the same work order (By work order ID - see image in original question)

Comment: are `op no=10` exits in database and if crystal is picking then there is no way that crystal doesn't pick those... check your record selection formula may be it is filtering your op no=10.... now in preview can you see op no=10 then my solution works perfectly... I would suggest to first check in database level for op no=10 exists or not

Comment: I think the problem with record selection is that we use a sort of databse front-end called "E-max", which essentially filters the results onlt to show one's specific to a certain machine on the shopfloor. The record selection bit in crystal is blank (until i tried your solution), however I believe that there is something happening between E-max and crystal which is automatically filtering the results by `Work Centre Name` (name of machine).EDIT:  For example, when I click `verify Database` it asks to `Select Recordset`, does this have anything to do with the problem? Thanks

Comment: Yeah OP=10 does exist, however OP 10 is always a different `Work Centre Name` which I believe is filtered either by E-max or crystal, probably emax because crystal record selection is blank...

Comment: ok then in that case use only crystal record selection and check by providing only date so that it will return all op records